# Does a moving atom with a nuclear magnetic moment generate an electric field?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, nuclear-physics, ions, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

I have read that moving ions generate a magnetic field as it moves.

Similarly, is this also true regarding the nuclear magnetic moments of the atom? In other words, would a moving atom with a nuclear magnetic moment generate an electric field as it moves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The magnetic moment has a corresponding magnetic field. As the atom moves through the lab the B-field in the space around atom (in the lab frame, not in the atom's frame) will change. This changing B-field creates electric fields as per Faraday's law.

Comment: I see, so for an atom with no nuclear magnetic moment, the electric field generated will be significantly weaker than for an atom with a nuclear magnetic moment?

Comment: Well... atoms with or without nuclear magnetic moments generate electric fields due to the charge separation between the positive nucleus and the negative electrons. My strong guess is that for non-relativistic velocities these fields are MUCH larger than the "Faraday" fields due to the moving magnetic atom. I'm not sure how fast the ion would have to be moving before the Faraday fields become dominant..

Comment: Getting quantitative about this would also require a much more sophisticated relativistic discussion than I'm presenting here. My answer here is just saying: moving magnets create electric fields.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Is there a good textbook where I can learn more about what you mentioned in the comments above? Also, it is significant that a moving magnet can create electric fields at even the atomic scale since strange things can happen at those sizes.

Comment: The standard reference here is Jackson Classical Electrodynamics. For the quantum part I'd suggest studying spin-orbit coupling and hyperfine structure. If you understand those deeply it will help with understanding for your question. My go-to book for quantum/atom stuff is Steck Quantum and Atom Optics, but there are likely better ones for this question, more focused on atomic structure. If this answers your question you click the check mark to accept the answer.

Comment: Got it, thank you!